# Why is the Logins property null?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to add a Windows user to an SQL Server. This works fine. However, if the user is already there, I don't want to get an error. If it's already there, that's fine. So I thought I would just check before creating it:

```
$AccountName  = $args[0]
$ComputerName = $args[1]
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
$sqlSrv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' ($ComputerName)

$sqlSrv.Refresh() # TRIED DIFFERENT THINGS HERE, REFRESH, INITIALIZE...

$login = $sqlSvr.Logins[$AccountName] # HERE .Logins IS NULL

if ($login -eq $null) {
    $login = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login' ($sqlSrv, $AccountName)
    $login.Name = $AccountName
    $login.LoginType = 'WindowsUser'
    $login.PasswordPolicyEnforced = $false
    $login.Create()
}
```

I don't know why the `Logins` Property of the SQL Server class is null. I can see the existing logins in SQL Management Studio.

Can anybody tell me how to properly check if a login exists before creating it? With Roles and Databases, the Server's properties seem to be filled.

I'm using Sql Server Express Version 11.0.5058.0 (I think that's 2012) and Powershell Version is 5.0.10586.117.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @ChrisAlbert Updated the post with versions.

Comment: If you attempt to do $login = $sqlSrv.logins without the filtering parameter it returns nothing?

Comment: @ChrisAlbert Yes, the `.Logins`property is `null`, any kind of index access or calling `.Contains` on it will result in a corresponding error. For example "Cannot index into a null array." for the array indexer.

Comment: Just run $login = $sqlSrv.logins then on the next line simply have just $login. This should output all of the logins to your console.

Comment: @Chris I know what it *should*. Unfortunately it doesn't. It does not print anything, because it's null.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. The $sqlSrv.Refresh() statement seems to be unnecessary though. That causes a null reference when I use it. Have you tried with a higher privileged account?

Comment: @Chris Well, I have enough privileges to *create a new* user, so I'd guessed I can see the existing users. The Refresh statement was just grasping at straws because it might have worked. It wasn't there at the beginning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to this $sqlS**v**r.Logins to $sqlSrv.Logins

```
$sqlSvr.Logins to $sqlSrv.Logins
```

Comment: Holy sh*t you are right. This is why I hate scripting, trying to be easy on the user leaving enough rope to hang himself. Thanks a lot.